# How can I setMaxDate() for DatePicker to one month after the current date?

Tags: java, android, datepicker, android-datepicker, android-date

Here's my `onCreateDialog`:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, dpickerListener, year_x, month_x, day_x);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate();
```

As you can see, `setMaxDate()` is empty. I want to set the max date of the `datePickerDialog` to one month after the current date.
Here's how I get the current date:

```
cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentDay = cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    currentMonth = cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    currentYear = cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setDate(currentDay);
    currentDate.setMonth(currentMonth);
    currentDate.setYear(currentYear);
```

Comment: try set currentMonth = cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH+1); may be set current month +next month work

Comment: else there is a long way to set next month comes in calander at current date ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this snippet

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance()
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,1)
long afterTwoMonthsinMilli=cal.getTimeInMillis()
    DatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(afterTwoMonthsinMilli);
```

It reads the current system date into a calendar object and adds 1 to the specified field,In this case `MONTH` and returns a calendar object

Similarly if you want to add values to other fields,Specify the field in the field type as:

- `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`
- `Calendar.YEAR`
- `Calendar.HOUR`

etc.

Comment: Doesn't work; `Add` is not a method. `add` is, however it doesn't implement `getTimeInMillis()`

Comment: I would +1 if I could

Comment: But since you explained, I will choose your answer as correct

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis);
```

You can use "add" to add to the `Calendar.MONTH`

Answer (score 0):

you have to override OnDateChangedListener
`new OnDateChangedListener() {

```
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
                    int month, int day) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

                if (calendar.before(newDate)) {
                    view.init(minYear, minMonth, minDay, this);
                }
            }
        });`
```