# How to disable past and future month in Android date picker?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I am trying to create a datePicker in which the previous and upcoming months will be disable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545374/how-can-i-setmaxdate-for-datepicker-to-one-month-after-the-current-date https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258995/android-datepicker-shows-unavailable-months-when-using-min-max-limits

Answer (score 2):

You should specify for the disable dates,

Inside the DATE_DIALOG_ID:

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 int cyear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 int cmonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 int cday = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

 DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth, cday);
 datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
 datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

requres minimum api level 11.

**OR** 
If you are using calendar,

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Hope this will for work for your code.

Comment: This disable all my date except my current date. But I need all dates in a month. I just need to disable swiping current month to another month.

Answer (score 0):

`datePicker.setMaxDate(date.getTimeInMillis());` for maximum
`datePicker.setMinDate(date.getTimeInMillis());` for minimum